How to customize syslog message parameters in particular log call using logback syslog appender?
I've read this chapter:
https://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#SyslogAppender
And now I understand how to configure syslog logback appender:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE configuration>

<configuration>
  <import class="ch.qos.logback.classic.net.SyslogAppender"/>

  <appender name="SYSLOG" class="SyslogAppender">
    <syslogHost>remote_home</syslogHost>
    <facility>AUTH</facility>
    <suffixPattern>[%thread] %logger %msg</suffixPattern>
  </appender>

  <root level="DEBUG">
    <appender-ref ref="SYSLOG"/>
  </root>
</configuration>

But it is a global configuration. And syslog it is not only destination of where to write but also a format:
What if I want to log to a different facility in particular place ? or use particular log level in syslog format ?
Is there way to achieve it ?
I would expect that I can pass special message like https://github.com/jenkinsci/syslog-java-client/blob/master/src/main/java/com/cloudbees/syslog/SyslogMessage.java
and fill in all the fields I need

Have you thought of multiple appenders? If so, what is the challenge with them?

@Naman I didn't get why did you ask ? This question about customization of particular syslog appender. In the place where I write log.... "my log message" I want to choose log level (in syslog format), facility etc

@Naman if am not mistaken appender is a mean which allow to write logs to additional locaton (file, consolse, smtp....etc). So if I have 2 locations- message will be written to 2 appenders, But My question is about format of single message for particular appender
